# Trouble with MultiChoiceModeListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a MultiChoiceModeListener set up on a ListView with a custom list adapter. The list is composed of relative layouts with a single text view and an icon to indicate click ability.

The `MultiChoiceModeListener` is set up with the `onItemCheckedStateChanged` like this:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(
        ActionMode mode,
        int position, 
        long id, 
        boolean checked) {
    Log.d(TAG, (checked ? "Checked" : "Un-checked"));
    if (checked) {
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                Color.parseColor("#6633b5e5"));
    } else {
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    }
}
```

Now, the problem here is that when the user long presses the list, initiating the chooser the first item is not colored. The Log.d logs "Checked" but the color is not changed.

Other things inside the `if(checked)` test runs, but the color doesn't change. The next item clicked is colored, and if I un-check and re-check the element the color changes properly.

It works if I set the list adapter to a default one:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So it seems it just doesn't work with my custom layout. What gives?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @Prabs, the app I was using this in now works as it should. I haven't checked the source code of the app to see how I did it so I might have changed to a different solution. Let me know if you want me to check how I did it.